# Abstract class with private derived classes: implement method for some

Tags: c#, inheritance

I made a class to generate 2 similar but yet very different reports. For that I used the pattern I found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29907649/3410196
It uses an abstract baseclass, which contains private derived classes with public constructors, so other code can never actually access the constructors of the derived class, and only create objects by using the `static Create()` method.

Now I'm facing a problem:
Everything works fine and I can export the reports etc. But now I have to be able to export **one** of the reports in a different format. Is there any way I can make this method accessible through the base class only for that one derived class? Otherwise I'll have to `throw new NotImplementedException()` or force my users to use something like this:

```
//Is actually multiReport (multireport:report)
Report report = Report.Create(...);
MemoryStream stream = (report as multireport).ExportOtherFormat();
```

I doubt this is possible but maybe there is a way!

Comment: Create a class whose responsibility is the exporting of your reports. Eg, you could have a CSV exporter, an XML exporter, etc.  That class will take your report base class as a parameter.  The creation and exporting of your reports are likely two separate responsibilities so they should be in different classes.

Comment: Indeed I should've implemented it like that from the beginning, that would be much better. However it's too late now because too many applications already use my library. Lesson learned I guess

Comment: Can you not then just add another method to your library that takes an IExporter as a parameter?  You can then create a few exporters and the users of your library can then say how they want it exporting by passing in the appropriate exporter implementation?  Eg, public void Export(IExporter exporter)

Comment: So I make the exporters and instantiate it in my static Create methods or something?

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of whoever is using your report class, would do that. Something along the lines of Report report = Report.Create();  report.Export(new XmlExporter());

Comment: You could also have an overridden Create method that takes an IExporter, so if they use the default Create method they get the standard export method, but they can use new functionality by calling the overridden Create.

Comment: I need to avoid that other code should be adopted to my library. Something to keep in mind the next time i make a project like this :)

Comment: I just made the ReportA class public and added the Export method there. Ugly solution but it'll do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all I went for a solution (maybe not the best) to make one of the classes public and expose the method like that, but not have it on the other subclasses:

```
abstract class Report
{
private Report() {}

public abstract MemoryStream ExportPDF() { ... }  

public class ReportA : Report
{
    public ReportA() { ... }
    public override MemoryStream ExportPDF() {...}
    public MemoryStream ExportCSV() {...}
}

private class ReportB : Report
{
    public ReportB() { ... }
    public override MemoryStream ExportPDF() {...}
}

public static Report Create() { ... }
}
```

Now only subclass A has the method `ExportCSV()` and shows it. Now people can call the constructor to make a sublcass A however, which I don't really like

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make a method of one of the subclasses visible to outside users, because they create an instance of the base class (i.e. `basereport`, not `multireport`). They wouldn't be able to call `ExportOtherFormat` unless they know that they are looking at an instance of `multireport`, not `basereport`.

One way to work around this issue is to hide the format decision from the users as well. Make an `enum` of formats, and make `ExportWithFormat` method that takes it:

```
[Flags]
enum ReportFormat {
    Simple    = 1
,   Extended  = 2
,   Special   = 4
,   Multifile = 8
}
```

Add these properties and methods to the base class:

```
public ReportFormat AvailableExportFormats { get {... } }

public MemoryStream ExportWithFormat(ReportFormat format);
```

Now your `Multireport` can return the special flag for the extra format that it supports in `AvailableExportFormats`, and produce the proper export when that flag is passed back to it in `ExportWithFormat` method.

Comment: That would work, however I have other report classes too which all implement my PDF and Excel interface, so it would become inconsistent. I guess I have no other choice though. The factory idea of Darren is something I should've implemented from the beginning, but it's a bit too late now.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you need something like that, so that ReportB will provide new implementation of Export method:

```
abstract class Report
{
    private Report() {}

    public virtual MemoryStream Export() { ... }  

    private class ReportA : Report
    {
        public ReportA() { ... }
    }

    private class ReportB : Report
    {
        public ReportB() { ... }
        new public virtual MemoryStream Export() { ... }
    }

    public static Report Create() { ... }
}
```

Comment: If I do that if I create a Report like that, even if it's a ReportA it will still show the method

Comment: I thought you need just another implementation of method Export. In case you need a separate method - suggestion made by @DarrenYoung will be the best way to go, I think.

Comment: Yes indeed, should've thought more about it when I started with this project